# How to find another linearly independent solution to a linear system $\dot{\mathbf{x}}=A(t)(\mathbf{x}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

Given a non-autonomous linear system
$$\dot{\mathbf{x}}=A(t)\mathbf{x}$$ with $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

If one has one solution, how would they find another independent solution?

How many linearly independent solutions are there?

Comment: If the system is autonomous $A$ cannot be time dependent I believe?

Comment: meant to say non-autonomous, apologies!

Comment: Hint: think about $x(t) = \exp\left(\int_0^t A(s)ds\right)x_0$ for $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Not sure, I've looked at it haha

Comment: @infinitylord That only holds if $\left[A(t),A(t')\right]=0$ for all $t,t'$.

Comment: Ah, is it that we get a matrix whose columns are solutions? So potentially n independent solutions? W